# angular ui bootstrap uib-tooltip show on custom trigger

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this tooltip on a input field:

```
<input id="chatMsg" uib-tooltip="something" tooltip-trigger="openTrigger" ng-model="chatMsg" />
```

and i want to show it on a custum trigger like this:

```
angular.element('#chatMsg').trigger('openTrigger');
```

but i can't get it to work, on my previus versions of ui-bootstrap-tpls it was working (0.12.1) now i've upgraded to 0.14.3

i've also configured the provider like this:

```
app.config(['$uibTooltipProvider', function ($uibTooltipProvider) {
    $uibTooltipProvider.setTriggers({
        'openTrigger': 'closeTrigger'
    });
}]);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

From version 0.12.0 onwards, tooltip-trigger is no longer observable (so you are not able to change it programatically).

You can use tooltip-enable to get the same behavior. See more details here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3372